# How do I test a site on localhost as if it is on a live domain (using IIS 7)

Tags: testing, windows-server-2008, localhost, domain-name

Ok, I have a local site called located here: http://localhost/mysite/

I want to be able to type http://www.mysite.com and for that to pose as the above mentioned.

I am using Windows Server 2008 / IIS 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert but this looks helpful: [Redirect URL to localhost](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/redirect-url-to-localhost-593608/)

> would an entry to /etc/hosts pointing that name to 127.0.0.1 not
>   suffice? you wouldn't be able to route to that hostname, but i guess
>   that's imaterial really. you could also use a browser plugin for
>   developers which allows you to specify arbitrary headers, i.e. in
>   firefox you could go to http://127.0.0.1 but include a HOST header for
>   the clients domain name which apache would then act upon. i expect a
>   /etc/hosts is probably all you really want.